# Forms [ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error]

Tags: sql, forms, oracle, oracle11g, ora-12560

I have oracle 11g database and using oracle forms and report 11g for created form by oracle.
I installed all of below software successfully(32 bit):

```
1- oracle 11g
2- JDK 1.6
3- web logic 11.
4- oracle forms and report.
```

but when I want to run a form it has the erro(ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error).
image show the forms:
[image]

after run the form it does this error(before run form I started the weblogic server):
[image]

Comment: everything including the DB installed on the same machine? Is the DB service running?

Comment: yes in the same machine. All DB service is running.

Comment: I think you can check this post it has all the necessary set up. [link](http://weblogic-corner.blogspot.com/2012/11/oracle-forms-and-reports-quick-start.html)